# Working with different versions of jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker

## Use case

I've got a conflict between jstree and jquery-ui datepicker.

I'm trying to use jquery-ui-datepicker on an input injected in DOM after AJAX request.

I'm using jsTree 3.3 which uses jQuery 3.1.1 and jQueryUI v1.12.1 which uses jQuery 1.12.4.
Issue

When I try to call `$('#datepicker').datepicker()`, it throws a TypeError

> (...).datepicker is not a function

## What I've tried so far

According to many other topics, including both following:

conflict between datepicker and jstree or multipul

putting datepicker() on dynamically created elements - JQuery/JQueryUI

My code looks like so:

*HTML:*

```
<script src="{% static 'Syc/js/jquery.js' %}"></script>
<script src="{% static 'Syc/js/jquery-old.js' %}"></script> <!-- version1.12.14-->
<script src="{% static 'Syc/js/jquery-ui/jquery-ui.js' %}"></script>
<script src="{% static 'Syc/Jstree/dist/jstree.min.js' %}"></script>
```

*Javascript:*

```
$(document).on('focus', "[id^='Date']", function () {
var jQ = jQuery.noConflict(true);
jQ.getScript('path/jquery-old.js', function () {
    jQ(function () {
        jQ(this).datepicker();
    })
});
```

Code above is currently placed in the success callback of the function that injects the input in the DOM.

This is the most advanced version of my JS, I've tried without getScript, I've tried to place it before/after jstree objects creation. I've no idea of what I'm missing or the correct way to make that datepicker() work.

Many thanks in advance for any help !

## Additional info

I'm working on Web app using Django Framework. $("#datepicker").datepicker() works fine in views where I dont use jstree, so according to what I've read I'm quite sure it's a conflit between the two plugins, very probably related to jQuery versions.

Comment: Why do you need 2 versions of jquery?

Comment: The getScript function will not ensure that the library is binded to the correct version. It only adds and loads the script in the dom.

Comment: I dont need it actually, but I found jQuery 1.12.4 file in jquery-ui/external/jquery.js so I supposed it's the version the plugin uses. I've also tried to remove it or replace it with my jquery 3.x file but it didnt fixe the issue.

Answer (score 1):

You say *"jQueryUI v1.12.1 which uses jQuery 1.12.4"*. On what basis have you decided this requirement?

http://jqueryui.com/download/ simply lists the download for UI 1.12.1 like this:

> 1.12.1 (Stable, for jQuery1.7+) requires jquery 1.7 or above.

To corroborate, http://api.jqueryui.com/ states very clearly

> jQuery UI 1.12    supports jQuery 1.7 and newer.

No specific version is mentioned apart from that minimum requirement. There's no reason you can't use 3.x with it. Having multiple versions of jQuery in your page (or even multiple copies of the same version) is a recipe for trouble, as you've discovered.

To solve your problem you can simply remove jquery 1.12.4 from your project completely.

Comment: Well actually I found  jQuery 1.12.4 file in jquery-ui/external/jquery.js

I've tried to remove it and replace it with 3.x file. 

Also before facing this issue I didnt include old-jquery.js in my scripts declaration.

Comment: yes but that's just what it happens to be packaged with. You're not required to use that version, as the documentation clearly states. You say "I've tried to remove it and replace it with 3.x file."...well don't. Don't replace it with anything. Just use your Syc/js/jquery.js (which I assume contains version 3.1.1?) and use it **once** in your whole page. As I mentioned above, don't have multiple copies loaded, even if they're the same version. Once you've verified that only one copy of jQuery is being loaded into the page, then if you still have an issue, we can look at it again in detail

Comment: Allright so that's exactly what I did in the first place (you're right Syc/js/jquery.js is 3.1.1) , but then I got the TypeError "datepicker is not a function". As you can see in additional info, it only happens in templates where I've both jstree and jquery-ui. I removed the jquery-old.js import and returned jquery-ui folder to its original state but cant get it working.

Comment: Btw, if that can be of any help, other jquery-ui tools such as dialog boxes work fine in this view.

Comment: does the element $('#datepicker') exist _before_ you run the .datepicker command? And does the jquery-ui file get loaded before you run the .datepicker command? If you remove jstree from those templates temporarily, does the datepicker work?

Comment: Yes to both first questions. I've also added a "foo" field in the html and tried datepicker() on it but it wont work also. And i've just tried to remove all extra scripts except of jquery and jquery-ui and .datepicker() doesnt work too. I'm quite confused ..

Comment: Without additional script:

$(function(){$('#datepicker').datepicker()})

jQuery.Deferred exception: $(...).datepicker is not a function @debugger eval code:1:14
mightThrow@http://localhost:8000/static/Syc/js/jquery.js:3570:21
resolve/</process<@http://localhost:8000/static/Syc/js/jquery.js:3638:12

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/yj5upmu9/ shows a minimal example using jQueryUI 1.12 and jquery 3.1.1. So it's definitely not a library issue. I can't see all of your code so it's hard to see what exactly is going wrong unfortunately. Clearly something else is coming into play, but without seeing the whole page code it's impossible to be sure. You definitely loaded jquery.js before jquery-ui.js? And definitely there are no other JS files loaded (check your browser's network tools to be sure)

Comment: I'm out for today, will try this tomorrow. Thanks for your answers anyway.

Comment: I've finally got it working. As weird as it may seems, I've replaced <script src="{% static 'Syc/js/jquery-ui/jquery-ui.js' %}"></script> with <script src="{% static 'js/jquery-ui.js' %}"></script> and now I can use datepicker(); 

I actually dont understand why is this working, since dialog boxes were  fine with previous path (they still do with this one) and this path is in fact "false" as I have no jquery-ui.js in my js folder. I'm definitely confused.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [jQuery-migrate](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-migrate).

It restores the APIs that were removed in newer versions of jQuery.

In your web page, load the plugin after the script tag for jQuery, for example:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.0.0.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-3.0.1.js"></script>
```

Check out the [documentation](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-migrate) on GitHub for more information.

Hope this helps!

Comment: this isn't required. jQuery UI works fine with newer jQuery as clearly stated on the website. The issue OP is having is conflicts due to having 2 versions on the page at once.

Comment: I'd rather not use more external plugin and I think I can solve this in a more "proper way".